# Expanding hand reach on piano

Tags: piano

My hand is decently small, and it's very difficult for me to play a series of octaves for a long time. The piece I'm playing has a bunch of octaves for a couple measures, and I'm wondering if there's anything I can do (other than practice the 
song multiple times)

Comment: Can you play a single octave, or do you have to play broken octaves?

Comment: In this piece, can you "cheat" and play at least some of those notes with the other hand, to give the octave hand some relief?

Comment: No because on the other hand I have to play arpeggios but my piano teacher did suggest that when I could. :)

Answer (score 1):

Stretching out a hand is stressful on the abductors to begin with and pulls it in multiple directions.  Compound that with flexing or extending and you will create much tension. All tension comes from trying to use two muscles at the same time to move one bone in two directions.

Make sure you are playing with the weight of the arm or gravity.  Between each drop of the arm, make sure (if there is time) to allow your hand do adduct.  Don't hold an abduction.  Especially if there is flexion involved. You may be able to use momentum from rotation the pronator and supinator muscles to spread the hand out rather than abducting.

If you can at least reach the octave, then the tension isn't from the stretch alone.